# firestore getDocs() methods are not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pull documents from a collection in firestore. When I try to iterate through the promise returned by getDocs() using the forEach() function I get an error saying: `TypeError: query.forEach is not a function. (In 'query.forEach(function (doc) {console.log(doc.data());})', 'query.forEach' is undefined)`. Additionally when I try to log the number of documents in the getDocs() query my program does not recognize size as a property and prints undefined. **

### Here is the documentation for getDocs():

**

```
export declare class QuerySnapshot<T = DocumentData> {
    /**
     * Metadata about this snapshot, concerning its source and if it has local
     * modifications.
     */
    readonly metadata: SnapshotMetadata;
    /**
     * The query on which you called `get` or `onSnapshot` in order to get this
     * `QuerySnapshot`.
     */
    readonly query: Query<T>;
    private constructor();
    /** An array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`. */
    get docs(): Array<QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>>;
    /** The number of documents in the `QuerySnapshot`. */
    get size(): number;
    /** True if there are no documents in the `QuerySnapshot`. */
    get empty(): boolean;
    /**
     * Enumerates all of the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`.
     *
     * @param callback - A callback to be called with a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` for
     * each document in the snapshot.
     * @param thisArg - The `this` binding for the callback.
     */
    forEach(callback: (result: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>) => void, thisArg?: unknown): void;
    /**
     * Returns an array of the documents changes since the last snapshot. If this
     * is the first snapshot, all documents will be in the list as 'added'
     * changes.
     *
     * @param options - `SnapshotListenOptions` that control whether metadata-only
     * changes (i.e. only `DocumentSnapshot.metadata` changed) should trigger
     * snapshot events.
     */
    docChanges(options?: SnapshotListenOptions): Array<DocumentChange<T>>;
}
```

### my code:

### getPrData

```
const getPrData = async () => {
  const colRef = collection(db, "UsersData");
  const q = query(colRef, where("Exercise", "==", "Bench"));  
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
  
    return (
      querySnapshot
);
```

### **Trying to iterate through querySnapshot**

```
export default LogDrop = () => {
    const query = getPrData();
        useEffect(()=>{
         query.forEach((doc)=>{
              console.log(doc.data());
          });
        console.log(query.size())
    },[])
```

When I simply log query from LogDrop this is the output:

```
Promise {
  "_A": null,
  "_x": 0,
  "_y": 0,
  "_z": null,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPrData` returns a promise. You need to `await` that promise in order to get the snapshot

```
export default LogDrop = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
      const snapshot = await getPrData();
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
      });
      console.log(snapshot.size());
      // probably set state at this point
    };

    load();
  }, []);
```